# Importance of MySQL field types

Tags: mysql

In a MySQL table, I have several columns - some containing strings, some dates or numbers.  I have always just made each field varchar(200).  What are the benefits of creating more appropriate field types?  Will select queries become faster?

Comment: The MySQL devs didn't go through all the trouble of supporting all those types solely for their own amusement...

Comment: what are the benefits of creating all fields as varchar(200)?

Comment: We get data from people producing CSV's in Stata.  We have a program to read the file, automatically create a sql table according to the column headings and insert all the rows.  It was convenient to just automatically create everything as varchar so that it doesn't require talking to a SQL guy everytime they change the format.  It works well, but now our tables are getting big and we are hitting performances issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using datatypes means that you'll be able to actually use the data in a meaningful way. For example, you can do date arithmetic (using DATE_ADD, for example).

It also means that ordering by numbers will work as expected (it won't with strings).

It also allows mysql to choose the appropriate amount/type of storage for the data you're representing.

There are many reasons, not least that it makes it easier for anyone else using your schema to know what kinds of values to expect. It also allows mysql to do validation on your data (what happens if your "date" column contains "Once in a blue moon"?)

Comment: Storage and comparison will also be more efficient.  e.g., an integer can be stored in around 4 bytes; the string representation make take 10 or more.  Comparing two 4 byte ints can be done in roughly a single CPU instruction; comparing two 10 byte strings representing the same int may take several.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes, they will most likely be faster.

If you have lots of rows, you'll save lots of disk space. For instance, an INT uses less space than VARCHAR(200). Also, choosing relevant column types will give you a certain measure of [type safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) (depending on how much typecasting your code or database will do for you).

Answer (score 1):

10x-100x speed when working with indexes in numeric fields

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you correctly, you store numbers and dates in varchar(200) columns?

Well, you can't compare dates, make calculations with the numbers etc. that way.

Consider a query like the following:

```
SELECT    yourfieldlist
FROM      YourTable
WHERE     DateColumn > '2009-10-01'
```

This won't work as expected if DateColumn is a varchar(200). So, it is important to use appropriate types for columns.

If you just use this one datatype, why even bother using a database? Just stuff your data in a textfile.

Comment: Honestly, the date comparison will actually probably work okay -- that's the whole point of the YYYY-MM-DD date format.  It sorts naturally.  Still, not using proper types is a very bad idea.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But that's not the only supported date format, is it?

Answer (score 0):

The type tells the DBMS how to compare against that field. This allows you to, for example, find rows where date_created > 'some date' easily.

In short, yes, your selects will be faster if you use the proper types and are comparing against those fields because MySQL will know how to better index your data to return results more efficiently. If you are just doing basic selects without any kind of join, where or order then you probably wont see speed improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Another benefit is that datatypes ensure the *correctness* of the data provided. Usually, anyways --- MySQL is not held in high regard for its correctness-ensurance. For example, `"laksjfd"` is not a valid date. Nor is `"2009-02-29"` --- but `"2012-02-29"` is. Those are all valid `varchar(200)`s, though.